# Expected value of characteristic function

Tags: probability

I was wondering about the expected value of the characteristic function $\chi_A$ for some set $A \in \mathcal{A}$ in a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$. It should be $\mathbb{E}(\chi_A) = \mathbb{P}(A)$, but I can't figure out why that is the case.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you know? What did you try?

Comment: Do you know how to compute the expectation for "simple functions"?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If $X$ is a random variable taking values in a countable set $S$ then: $$\mathbb EX=\sum_{s\in S}s.\mathbb P(X=s)$$

$\chi_A$ is actually a random variable taking values in $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Oh thanks! Got it now